# How can I create a script to change current user registry in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will modify a registry value for the current user.  The current user is not an admin.  The intent is for the script to challenge for admin user credentials when it is executed.

Many guides online say to run the PowerShell exe as admin, but the problem with that is that PS loads the admin user registry, not the current non-admin user.  And I cannot load the non-admin user registry from within the elevated PS session, because I am currently logged in as the non-admin user and the .dat file is locked.

One person suggested using the New-Item cmdlet with the -Credential flag, but PowerShell errors and says "the provider does not support the use of credentials" (despite the documentation for New-Item listing the credential flag as supported).

As it stands today, I have to log out of the non-admin user account, then log in as the admin user, then run the script (which has a command for loading the non-admin user registry profile), change the registry value, then log out of the admin user, then log back in as the non-admin user.  This seems excessively tedious.  I feel like there should be an easier solution - am I crazy?

In summary:
Ran New-Item as non-admin, don't have access to change the registry value.
Ran PowerShell as administrator, it loads the admin user registry and not the non-admin user registry.
Tried to load the non-admin user registry within the elevated PS session, it cannot load the file when the non-admin user is currently logged in.
New-Item documentation says it accepts -Credential, but in execution it rejects that flag as invalid.

Comment: Why would you need to run it as admin if the goal is for the user to modify their own hive?

Comment: So an admin can approach the machine with the script on a USB drive, pop it in and run the script, and then walk away.  It is faster in our scenario to address the change right on the machine than it is to do any remote PS execution.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the key path? I thought standard users could modify values under `HKCU` and admin was only needed for modifying `HKLM`...

Comment: Here's the path I'm using in the script:  Registry::HKEY_USERS\w9guest\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].